# How to properly use Scala Numeric typeclass and reuse its operations

Tags: scala, typeclass

As an exercise, I tried to create simple `Fraction` class which would support various numeric operations, and whatnot, but Scala's type system, rules for implicits, and (lack of) documentation, are making me really lost.

My current goal is to support two following test cases:

```
  it should "support arithmetic" in {

    val fraction1 = Fraction(3, 5)
    val fraction2 = Fraction(7, 10)

    val sum = fraction1 + fraction2
    assertResult(Fraction(13, 10))(sum)

    val diff = fraction1 - fraction2
    assertResult(Fraction(-1, 10))(diff)

    val prod = fraction1 * fraction2
    assertResult(Fraction(21, 50))(prod)

    val quot = fraction1 / fraction2
    assertResult(Fraction(6, 7))(quot)
  }

  it should "support sequence operations" in {

    val list = Fraction(1, 5) :: Fraction(0, 100) :: Fraction(2, 3) :: Nil
    val sum = list.sum
    assertResult(Fraction(13,15))(sum)
  }
```

Test case for "it should support arithmetic operations" I got covered with explicit methods defined in my class. Then I moved to "should support sequence operations" and, following some examples, I got it working by implementing `Numeric[Fraction]` typeclass in following way:

```
object Fraction {

  def apply(numerator: Int, denominator: Int): Fraction = ...
  def unapply(f: Fraction): Option[(Int, Int)] = ...

  trait NumericFraction extends Numeric[Fraction] {

    def fromInt(x: Int): Fraction = Fraction(x, 1)

    def minus(x: Fraction, y: Fraction): Fraction = {
      plus(x, negate(y))
    }

    def negate(x: Fraction): Fraction = Fraction(-x.numerator, x.denominator)

    def plus(x: Fraction, y: Fraction): Fraction = {  ... actual addition here ... }
    def times(x: Fraction, y: Fraction): Fraction = { ... multiplication here ... }

    def toDouble(x: Fraction): Double = x.numerator.toDouble / x.denominator

    ... other Numeric[T] implementations...
  }

  implicit object NumericFraction extends NumericFraction
}
```

Then I could change operators in my class to reuse implementations from `NumericFraction`:

```
class Fraction private (val numerator: Int, val denominator: Int)(implicit num: Fraction.NumericFraction) {
  import num._

  ... some stuff ...

  def +(other: Fraction): Fraction = plus (this, other)
  def -(other: Fraction): Fraction = minus(this, other)
  def *(other: Fraction): Fraction = times(this, other)

  ... more stuff ...
}
```

Things seem to work here, but I seem to miss some point: since I implemented `Numeric[Fraction]`, which in turn provides `Ops`, which in turn define arithmetic operators of `+`, `-` and `*`, can I reuse them somehow as arithmetic operators for my class, without defining operator methods explicitly in my class? If yes, how? If no, what are `Numeric[T].Ops` good for, then? As a noob who gets lost in implicits hell and who is full of expectations coming from misunderstood ideas, I would expect to be possible to omit `*` method in my class and use `Numeric[Fraction].Ops.*` instead in client code, in expressions like `val f3 = Fraction(n1, d1) * Fraction(n2, d2)` - what am I getting wrong?

Comment: Before the test `import Numeric.Implicits._` - BTW, do not use an **implicit object**, use an **implicit val** with an explicit type signature.

Comment: Following @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez suggestion to `import Numeric.Implicits._` obviously works, but it forces clients of my class to include this import in their code. Is this indeed intended way to use `Numeric[T].Ops`?

About `implicit val` vs `implicit object`, care to share some resources on that? I think I got this line from Scala source code Eclipse displayed me.

Thank you for your input!

Comment: Yeah either your clients have to import it, or you provide the methods yourself. _(hopefully Scala 3 will be better)_. One option would be to generate that code but probably that would be more work for just some boilerplate. - about the **implicit val**, the thing is that implicits are being resolved by type and **objects** have their own type, which can cause problems, it is not a formal resource, but you can check [this](https://github.com/BalmungSan/scala-functional-programming-tutorial/blob/master/scala-intro/src/main/scala/co/edu/eafit/dis/progfun/scala/intro/ImplicitsNotes.scala#L16)